# How close three View Controllers on last View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller with a View Controller displaying a button. The button is linked to another View Controller using a push segue which automatically adds a top navigation bar with a back button Im
Five View Controller when display View Controller Five Close Three View Controller Previous?

Example:A-B-C-D-E When display View Controller E CLOSE B-C-D

Comment: this is not possible in segue . Manually push E directly on your requirement

Comment: @Kavos Khajavi I know your want, at first you should recognize `Navigation  controller` 's  `viewControllers` is a ` stack` in memory, so you cannot remove `B-C-D`, If you want to pop to `A` from `E`,what you should do is use `storyboard` unwind to ` A` from `E`, or traverse the `navigation controllers` if the one equals to `A`, then `pop`  programly

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove `B-C-D` view controllers in a nav `stack`:

the simple example for your demand is like this:

[image: you can use storyboard to do your requirement]

In `AViewController.swift`:

```
@IBAction func unwindToAVCFromEVC (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let e_vc: EViewController = segue.source as? EViewController {

        print("to a_vc from e_vc")
    }
}
```

In `storyboard`, you just control-drag the `backToA` button to `exit`, choose the `unwindToAVCFromEVC`, so you can ease back to `AViewController`.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score -2):

I have checked this code and it works fine:)

```
NSMutableArray* viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//popup the last 3 screens.

for(int i = 0 ; i < [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] - 3 ; i++){

 [viewControllers addObject:self.navigationController.viewControllers[i]];

}

//add new screen.

[viewControllers addObject:newVC];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```